# External harddisk problem

Tags: external-hdd, transfer, io

The question title is obviously not clear because I am not sure what is going on.

I have a 1TB external HDD. I've always been using it on my old laptop. On my new laptop running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 I am trying to move some files to it. I tried the GUI and the cli  (cp -r & rsync).

The problem is the HDD seems to stop responding. For example, rsync hangs. It fails with a read-only filesystem error. The first time I was copying the files I saw this error so I plugged it into my old laptop and change the permissions of all enclosed files to read/write for all.

When I force stop the transfer (Ctrl+C) the command still appears in htop with status D.

The processes cannot be killed with either a 15 or 9 signal. Also I cannot unmount the disk. It says one or more processes are keeping the volume busy.

Comment: It's an, at least, 5 years old disk so I expect it to be usb2 but `lsusb -D` shows `bcdUSB` to by 3.00. EXT4 format. No Windows (no dual boot).

Comment: PS: The light on the disk has been turned on for quite a while. As far as I remember it used to be off when it's not being used and blink when being used.

Comment: @user10853 as I suggested... reboot first... then start `Disks`... then single-click on the external drive in the left pane... then select `SMART Data & Tests`. If you then can't select `SMART Data & Tests` then your external disk enclosure don't support it. Boo.

Comment: @DarkSinus thanks for the help, but I've got this. Check back later if I get stumped.

Comment: @heynnema I just tested it on my old laptop. It successfully transfered a 3.8GB both ways. No SMART doesn't show up in Disks. The disk comes with a double usb on on the other side. I've always used one usb. I cannot connect both on the new laptop as I only have one usb on each side and no hub.  No power supply. I believe I do have a legacy option and I think it is enabled as I needed it to install Ubuntu. I will recheck now.

Comment: Ah... you DO have a power problem. That double USB connection is because one USB port normally doesn't supply enough power for a 1TB drive. Your old laptop obviously supplies more power than the new laptop. You either need to get a short USB extension cable so that you can plug in BOTH USB ports for power, or get a powered USB hub, or plug in an optional power supply into the hard disk (if it supports it).

Comment: @heynnema regarding the legacy, I was mistaken. It was for the boot option not the USB.
mmh. I have another disk with a double usb but it is 500GB and it works fine. So 1TB + disks require more power?

Comment: @heynnema It seems to be running smooth now. I connected it to an external monitor which is connected to my laptop through usb.

Comment: @heynnema it was a power issue. This connection solved it. I was able to transfer one of the files I was trasnferring (6.8GB). Thank you for the help

Comment: @heynnema I checked the power on the old laptop & it shows 100mA. The new laptop shows 200mA. The power issue doesn't seem to make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

You have a 1TB external HDD that used to work fine on your old laptop, but fails to operate properly on your new laptop.

The 1TB external drive requires more power than one USB port can supply. (More so than a 500GB drive).

Either utilize the double USB cable supplied with the external HDD, or connect an external power supply to the external HDD (if it supports it), or obtain a POWERED USB hub.